# Angular 2: Display array in matrix format

Tags: arrays, angular, matrix, ngfor

I have a 1D array (list of people). I want to display this data in a matrix format in angular 2. The array looks like this:

```js
[
{Id: 1, FirstName: 'Michael', LastName: 'Jackson'},
{Id: 2, FirstName: 'Aamir', LastName: 'Khan'},
{Id: 3, FirstName: 'Meg', LastName: 'Ryan'},
{Id: 4, FirstName: 'Raj', LastName: 'Kumar'},
{Id: 5, FirstName: 'Michael', LastName: 'Jordan'},
{Id: 6, FirstName: 'Serena', LastName: 'Williams'},
{Id: 7, FirstName: 'Rathi', LastName: 'Agnihotri'},
]
```

The output needs to be:

```html
Michael Jackson                  Aamir Khan             Meg Ryan
Raj Kumar                        Michael Jordan         Serena Williams
Rathi Agnihotri
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Apologies for the incomplete post, Gunter. Updated the question

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/displaying-data.html SO is not a bunch of code monkeys. Your question should show your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I used bootstrap list-inline style to achieve this. Plus I added my own media queries like so.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 400px)  {
    .searchedItem {
        width: 94%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:401px) and (max-width: 768px)  {
    .searchedItem {
        width: 47.5%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:769px) and (max-width: 992px)  {
    .searchedItem {
        width: 23%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:993px) {
    .searchedItem {
        width: 19%;
    }
}
```